# Changing UILabel frame height inside tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get my UILabel text from remote url, and sometimes the text is too short/too long and I need to adapt my frame size to the text height.
I have implemented costume cell using `xib`.

[image: screenshot]

This is what I tried so far, which supposed to works, but don't work for a reason I can't understand:

```
 cell.fbLastObject.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",update.fbLastObject];
 [cell.fbLastObject sizeToFit];

 //Cell Size
 CGSize labelSize = [cell.fbLastObject.text sizeWithFont:cell.fbLastObject.font
                                       constrainedToSize:cell.fbLastObject.frame.size
                                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
 labelHeight = labelSize.height;
 cell.fbLastObject.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,labelHeight);
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Are you using Auto layouts?

Comment: Have you set the number of lines to 0.

Answer (score 1):

For `iOS 8 and later`, you can use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` Put the below code in the `viewDidLoad` is:

```
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  /* any estimated height but must be more than 2 */
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0;
  tableview.delegate = self;
  tableview.dataSource = self;
 // you have created the SimpleTableViewCell.xib, So you need to register that cell with table.
  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
  [tableview registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableViewCell"];
```

Now add proper `cell fbLastObject` constraints (top, bottom, leading and trailing) pins to super View & set the number of lines to 0

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableViewCell";

    SimpleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // here set text for your cell label 
    cell.fbLastObject.text = @"My Text";

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean this constraints? cuz it's not working http://i.imgur.com/q5g2Qpq.png

Comment: The constraints that you added as shown in screenshot are right, Actually I was thing that you have only a label in the cell of table that's why suggested following constrains top, bottom, leading and trailing pins to super View.
but as I can see in the screenshot label doesn't have right frame.

Comment: you should add sufficient, nonambiguous, satisfiable layout constraints for all subview of cell so that layout engine automatically calculate the tableview height for you.
if your constraints are correct, above code will work properly. if you have any issue, let me know, I'll help.

Comment: Hey, thanks. but I still don't get what's your solution. I don't know much about contrains and how they are supposed to be in this situation, this is my layout: http://i.imgur.com/J7zpgc1.png - if you have any idea how the constraints should be like I would love to know.. (As you can see in the screenshot above of a custom table cell xib, I have some labels, full width image and unknown-height text below it, which need to be responsive).

Comment: This is how my app really looks like when running with this constraints:  http://i.imgur.com/u9PYYwY.png(The image is cut, no text, and everything is too near each other)

Comment: First thing is that your constraints are neither correct nor satisfiable, as you can see in you .xib, there are some warning regarding to constraints which Xcode generates for you. Xcode lets you know that there are some thing wrong with constraints. so try to resolve them firstly ok.(see the red forward arrow in a view hierarchy of cell)

Comment: Second thing is that you have created Custom UITableViewCell using Nib (.xib) files in Xcode. so whenever you create a custom table cell using Nib then you must have register your costume cell in tableView using the -registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier: method of tableview but that doses not required in storyboard.

Comment: I have updated the code to register your costume xib cell on tableView so you can use that. Now you try to correct your constraints to complete your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try   self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

For dynamic cell using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

You can do by mapping Height Constraint of UILabel and calculate the size of the text from remote url and according to that calculated height return height of row and also give that height to mapped Height Constraint outlet and before return cell just write :-

[cell.UILabel updateConstraints];

Answer (score 0):

In your question the steps you took to get the size for the Label is fine. Make Label's property SizeToFit and NumberOfLines to 0 and add the appropriate constraints to it. Then create an instance of NSLayoutConstraint for Height constraint of Label and make it attach to bottom of UITableViewCell. Then when ever you have the CGSize from text then you need to call UpdateConstraintIfNeeded on self and then need to set height constant property for that Label's constraint & need to set the heightForRowAtIndexpath of UITableVIew.
Hope this will work.