# UITableViewCell systemlayoutsizefittingsize returns 0 height and gives constrains warning

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

**[IOS 7.0]** I have custom UITableViewCell and use `systemlayoutsizefittingsize:` to get the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but it gives me these warning and the height returned as 0. So whats wrong with my constrains?

PS: If I use fix height (let's say 200px) the constrains works

PPS: I use `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]`

PPPS: This constrain `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa4df50 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feafaa3c0b0.height == 0.5>"` added automatically when I use `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]`

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa3f570 UILabel:0x7feafaa3f7d0.height == 18>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa40540 UILabel:0x7feafaa407e0.height == 25>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa42010 UILabel:0x7feafaa3f210.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feafaa3c0b0.top + 18>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa421a0 UILabel:0x7feafaa3f7d0.top == UILabel:0x7feafaa3f210.bottom + 4>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa422e0 GCTLabelEllipsis:0x7feafaa3fd70.top == UILabel:0x7feafaa3f7d0.bottom - 2>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa42380 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feafaa3c0b0.bottom == UILabel:0x7feafaa407e0.bottom + 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa423d0 UILabel:0x7feafaa407e0.top == GCTLabelEllipsis:0x7feafaa3fd70.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa4df50 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feafaa3c0b0.height == 0.5>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feafaa40540 UILabel:0x7feafaa407e0.height == 25>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**EDIT**

This is my layout (they are in the same level under contentView)

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                           | 18                                            |
| -- 12 -- UIImageView (w 20) -- 12 --  UILabel - 0 lines word warp -- 6 -- UIlabel -- 8 -- |
|                                           | 4                                             |
|                                       UILabel - 1 lines trailing, h = 18                  |
|                                           | -2                                            |
|                                       GCTLabelEllipsis (UILabel) - 0 line word warp       |
|                                           | 8                                             |
|                                       UILabel - 1 line trailing, h = 25                   |
|                                           | 16                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: add more details about you cell view hierarchy and its constraints by a screenshot of cell so that I can look and may help you to get rid out of it

Comment: @keshavvishwkarma edited with my layout

Comment: your constrains look correct, but your calculated height  using heightForRowAtIndexPath method not correct & you don't need to calculate height you should use the UITableViewAutomaticDimension. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012760/changing-uilabel-frame-height-inside-tableview-cell/36018296#36018296

Comment: @keshavvishwkarma forgot to mention, my app support ios 7.0 so I cant use that

Comment: Now days only 5% user are using iOS 7 or earlier iOS version as apple mention in Apple's App Store support page for developers https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ So you can go with the majority of user

Comment: @keshavvishwkarma In my case, I still have 10% users that use ios 7, and they're quite active so I can't just ignore them ^_^